# Finding zero pixels in an image without counting ones near nonzero ones

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a very large image that has large regions of zero pixels and regions with data that have zero pixels sprinkled in. I want to flag all the zero pixels that are not within regions of data ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7bmF.jpg)). Normally using np.where(data == 0) would work but this clearly includes regions with data. I've tried using a method where I list each zero pixel and find the ones that have nonzero neighbors but that takes a very long time. The data is quite large and I'd like to find a fast way to do this if possible. The output I'm looking for is just a simple mask array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation` to label all nonzero pixels and all their neighbors:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.ndimage import morphology
>>> 
>>> a = (np.random.random((10, 10)) < np.clip(np.exp(np.arange(-5, 5)), None, 0.8)).view(np.uint8)
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
>>> 
>>> mask = morphology.binary_dilation(a)
>>> mask.view(np.uint8)
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

The default "structuring element" (which controls what is considered a neighbor) has four neighbors, but you can also specify 8 or some arbitrary mask.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to convolve your image with a 3x3 square tophat kernel. I'd use scipy's ndimage convolution filter:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html

Using a tophat, any pixel in the convolved image that has activated neighbors will be nonzero. Any pixel with no active neighbors will be zero.

You could also try experimenting with different kernels as well as bitwise operations on sets of filters to determine the final mask.